# Jenkins and updating git submodules

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, git-submodules

I am using Jenkins "Advanced sub-modules behaviour" and checked the "Recursively update sub modules" option. However I get the submodule only in an old revision. I would like to always have the head revision of the submodule. I found another option in "Advanced sub-modules behaviour" called "Update tracking submodules to tip of branch". This seems to use the --remote option. Will this solve the Problem?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [documentation page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) for submodule, it seems that that should work. You need to have git 1.8.2 or newer though.

Comment: Thanks I tried that it works, i checked "Recursively update sub modules" and "Update tracking submodules to tip of branch".