# unable to checkout git submodules in jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I've been trying unsuccessfully to configure a jenkins job that should clone a git repo with submodules. Everything goes fine until it hits "git submodule update" where it returns the following error:

`12:03:17 Submodule '<name>' (https://<url>.git) registered for path '<name>'
12:03:17 + git submodule update
12:03:17 Cloning into '<name>'...
12:03:18 fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
12:03:18 fatal: clone of 'https://<name2>' into submodule path 'data_gateway' failed
12:03:18 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
12:03:18 Finished: FAILURE`

I can clone the main repo with ssh using my user name (not jenkins)
I've tried to create keys for Jenkins user and add them to github and also tried with user and password but none of them gets rid of this issue.

Been reading loads but couldn't find any solution. Any pointers will be highly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471981/jenkins-and-updating-git-submodules this can help you? check your git version

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it adding the ssh keys for the jenkins machine to github and using ssh version of the remote url for the submodules. In jenkins' credentials configuration, you can set the actual ssh key of the machine.

Comment: After some research I found that moving conftest.py from the root folder to the tests/ folder fixes it but I've read somewhere that conftest.py should be on the root folder, so I'm not really happy with that solution